# Changing labels for linetype in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the legend title to Group and the values One and Two?

library(ggplot2)

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'),
                 val  = 1:4,
                 gr   = c('1', '1', '2', '2'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = val, linetype = gr, group = gr)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = 'Group', labels = c('one', 'two'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `scale_linetype_discrete` instead of `scale_linetype_manual`:

```r
df <- data.frame(date = c('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'),
                 val  = 1:4,
                 gr   = c('1', '1', '2', '2'))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = val, linetype = gr, group = gr)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = 'Group', labels = c(`1` = 'one', `2` = 'two'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>